# Bound of Coefficients of Fourier Series of Composition

Tags: fourier-analysis, inequalities, sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $f(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty f_ne^{inx} + \bar{f_n}e^{-inx}$ and $g(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty g_ne^{inx} + \bar{g_n}e^{-inx}$ where $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ and $g:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$. Both functions are uniformly continuous.

Suppose $f$ and $g$ are in $C^k$ with $|f_n|,|g_n| = O(n^{-k})$. Suppose
$$f\circ g(x) = h(x) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty h_ne^{inx} + \bar{h_n}e^{-inx}$$

Is there a better asymptotic approximation to $|h_n|$ than $O(n^{-k})$.
Can you give a bound if they are 1-Holder continuous? What if they are $\alpha$-Holder Continuous for $\alpha > 0$

Is there anything better you can say about the Fourier coefficient decay of $f(f(x))$ or $f^k(x)$ in general.

Comment: What do you mean with $f \circ g$ for $f$ defined on $\Bbb{R}$ or $\Im(x)\ge 0$ and $g$ complex valued

Comment: I edited the question.

Comment: $f$ is real valued iff its Fourier coefficients satisfy $F_{-n} = \overline{F_n}$. Also the decay of the Fourier coefficients depends on the local smoothnesses, and locally the composition of $C^k$ functions surjects on the $C^k$ functions.

Comment: I have added the negative terms. I had forgotten to. Is there some way to give a better bound like $O(n^{-k + \frac{1}{\log(n)}})$ I want to show that the decay of $f^p(x)$ is slower.

Comment: The coefficients of $h \in C^k$ are $o(n^{-k})$ and $\sum_n |H_n|^2 n^{2k} < \infty$. To get stronger bounds you need things like $a$-Hölder continuity of $h^{(k)}$

Comment: What if both functions are uniformly continuous.

Comment: A continuous periodic function always is uniformly continuous.

Comment: Can you give a bound if they are 1-Holder continuous? What if they are $\alpha$-Holder Continuous for $\alpha > 0$

Comment: Yes I know that. Is there anyhting better you can say about the Fourier coefficients of $f(f(x))$ or $f^k(x)$ in general.

Comment: The trick for the Hölder continuity is $F_n = \int_0^{2\pi} f(x) e^{-inx}dx =\int_0^{2\pi} f(x+\pi / n) e^{-in(x+\pi /n)}dx=- \int_0^{2\pi} f(x+\pi / n) e^{-inx}dx$, $ 2F_n = \int_0^{2\pi} (f(x)-f(x+\pi /n)) e^{-inx}dx$. If $|f(x)-f(x+y)| \le C  y^a$ then $|F_n| \le 2 \pi C  n^{1-a}$. I have explained why for the decay your function is just any $C^k$ function

Comment: Yes but this does not improve the bound for repeatedly composed functions.